# How do I combine arrays inside arrays into a single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
[[5],[27],[39],[1001]]
```

How can I convert it into this array in JavaScript?

```
[5,27,39,1001]
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Can the sub-arrays contain more than one element? Can they themselves contain sub-sub-arrays?

Answer (score 7):

Several ways to achieve the result

```js
var data = [
  [5],
  [27],
  [39],
  [1001]
];

// Use map method which iterate over the array and within the 
// callback return the new array element which is first element
// from the inner array, this won't work if inner array includes 
// more than one element
console.log(
  data.map(function(v) {
    return v[0];
  })
)

// by concatenating the inner arrays by providing the array of
// elements as argument using `apply` method
console.log(
  [].concat.apply([], data)
)

// or by using reduce method which concatenate array 
// elements within the callback
console.log(
  data.reduce(function(arr, e) {
    return arr.concat(e);
  })
)
```

Comment: nice solution all